# Maria DB gives weird output of select query

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

i have problem in this one table named as **post**
[image: image of table data]

and i fired this one query which is correct as my knowledge 
[image: image of fired query]
this is table structure or datatype
[image: datatype image]
and i am getting NULL but i have u_id = 1 in table for this row

is any ledgend of MYSQL is here to solve this?

and yah today is april fool day(1st April) but i taking swear of my mom that i am not here for make anyone fool.
so please take it as a serious

check out this video if you wan't belive https://youtu.be/jrjRyT6zNv0

Comment: Maybe your p_type is actually "q " or "q\n" or some other non-printing char.

Comment: Can you update your question with the column types? Also what happens if you run the query in MySQL Workbench?

Comment: i did it sir please check out this

Comment: Try `SELECT u_id FROM post WHERE q_a_c_id = 1` and `SELECT u_id FROM post WHERE p_type = 'q'` see which one gives you the NULL value.

Comment: What does your indexes look like?

Comment: @ThatGuyInIT sir, both gives NULL but from second query it gives three  row of NULL

Comment: Does this happen in MySQL Workbench or the mysql cli?

Comment: CLI gives error like "Some errors have been detected on the server!
As per your settings, they are being submitted currently, please be patient."

Comment: By [MySQL CLI](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysql-command-line-client/) I mean the command line, not in phpMyAdmin, we need to rule out phpMyAdmin.  What we need to know is if MariaDB is returning the correct result, but phpMyAdmin isn't displaying it correctly.  It would seem that way since you are getting the correct number of records back, but the values returned are all NULL.

Comment: You can also try one of these many other GUI MySQL tools 
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/graphical-and-enhanced-clients/

Comment: @ThatGuyInIT thank you sir, but i solved it by removing unnecessary bunch of indexes on u_id field which is cause collision i guess